# VBA to retrieve email addresses stored in a plaintext field of an access 2007 database?

Tags: vba, email, pdf, ms-access-2007

I'm developing an Access 2007 database in which I wish to automate the process of emailing a single daily report in *.pdf format to a number of recipients whose details will be stored in a table.

The structure of the table is as follows -

```
ID (AutoNumber)
RecipientName (Text) 
RecipientEmailAddress (Text)
Active (Yes\No)
```

The purpose of the Yes\No field is to ensure that only those people whose email address is currently marked as active get sent the reports.

If I have a query entitled qry_ActiveAddresses to extract only those addresses marked as active how do I go about getting VBA to do the rest? I want my users to click a button and have a report sent to each recipient **without opening Outlook**. For testing purposes at the moment I have a single hardcoded email address stored in a string variable which works as expected, but I'm not familiar enough with VBA to code this so am looking for help.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a recordset from the query and loop through it, with your mail code in the center of it all.  Maybe something like:

```
Public Sub SendEmails()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("qry_ActiveAddresses", dbOpenDynaset)

rst.MoveFirst

With rst 
  Do Until .EOF
     ' The following will print out your fields in the debug window

      Debug.Print .Fields("ID")
      Debug.Print .Fields("RecipientName")
      Debug.Print .Fields("RecipientEmailAddress")

      ' Your mail code would go here, using the values plugged in from above.

      .MoveNext
  Loop
End With

Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Drop that in a module and it should be clear what it does.  I am not in front of Access right now, but syntax looks ok.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks VBlades, sorry for not getting back to you sooner. With the code you provided hooked up to a button on a form I have it working more or less to my satisfaction. However, each time I click the button a small window pops up saying "Printing" & "Now outputting page 1 of x to a mail message". How do I prevent that from happening? I have not seen this window appear when I was developing on another machine.

Comment: No worries, glad it worked out for you.  As far as the dialog, not really sure.  How are you sending the mails, CDO?  And how are you outputting the PDF?  Does the dialog appear once for each email or once at the beginning of the process? I've done this with DoCmd.OutputTo in the past (not emails, but straight to PDF), and do remember a dialog similar to this one appearing.  Without knowing more, there is a rather invovled way here to try to rememdy the issue: http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0037.htm.

Comment: VBlades, I'm using the following line of code in the middle of the loop. **DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "rpt_Assignments", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "EmailAddress", "", , strSubjectMatter, strMessage, False**     strSubjectMatter and strMessage are both strings I've set up outside of the loop.

Comment: May be difficult/impossible.  See the thread here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0259597d-ec8e-453a-886a-f845748c5b80/docmdoutputto-pdf-suppress-message?forum=accessdev.  Am looking at another workaround now, but is a bit hacky and really depends on your situation.  Not even sure if it will work...

Comment: I tried to suppress Access' repainting of the screen with Application.Echo, but it does't work: the dialog in question is outside of Access's purview, it seems.  I think your best bet would be to check out the access.mvps.org link above.  Failing that, I think you will have to live with it, unfortunately.  Sorry.